# NgIf not displaying

Tags: ionic3

Provider work, but *ngIf not displaying.

In the image below, you can see that the provider loads the data but is not shown on the screen.

What could be wrong? The API is returning the data correctly, only the view is not happening.

[image: Error]

Arquivo.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CamaraProvider } from '../../providers/camara/camara';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-deputadodespesas',
  templateUrl: 'deputadodespesas.html',
  providers: [
    CamaraProvider
  ]
})
export class DeputadodespesasPage {

  public deputadoid;
  public deputadodespesa;   

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private view: ViewController ,public navParams: NavParams,private camaraProvider: CamaraProvider) {
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.view.dismiss();
  }


  ionViewWillLoad() {
    this.deputadoid = this.navParams.get("id");
    this.camaraProvider.getDespesaDeputado(this.deputadoid).subscribe(data => {
      let retorno = (data as any)._body;
      this.deputadodespesa = JSON.parse(retorno);
      console.log(retorno);
    }, error => {
    })
  }

}
```

Arquivo.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Despesas</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Fechar</button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card >

    <ion-card-content>
        <ion-item *ngIf="deputadodespesa" >                     
            <h3 class="message title">{{ deputadodespesa.nomeFornecedor }}</h3>
            <p>Services :</p>
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item ng-repeat="serv in servIn" class="message">
                <h4 class="title">{{ deputadodespesa.ano }}</h4>
                <p>{{ deputadodespesa.valorDocumento }}</p>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-item>

    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>


</ion-content>
```

Provider works perfectly, but does not show the results on the page.

Comment: `servIn` is not defined in `Arquivo.ts`.

Comment: your ion-list will not fit within an ion-item

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `ngIf` but rather your `ion-list` within an [`ion-item`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/). This tag has a fixed height. You will need to change it into a container tag like `div` or if you don't require an additional container, use `ng-container` which is for the case when you only need tags for additional angular directives.

```html
<ion-card >

    <ion-card-content>
        <ng-container *ngIf="deputadodespesa" > <!-- here -->                     
            <h3 class="message title">{{ deputadodespesa.nomeFornecedor }}</h3>
            <p>Services :</p>
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item ng-repeat="serv in servIn" class="message">
                <h4 class="title">{{ deputadodespesa.ano }}</h4>
                <p>{{ deputadodespesa.valorDocumento }}</p>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ng-container>

    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```